# Pyspark: explode columns to new dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Ihave some pyspark dataframe with schema:

```
 |-- doc_id: string (nullable = true)     
 |-- msp_contracts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _el1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _el2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _el3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _el4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _el5: string (nullable = true)
```

How do I get this data frame:

```
|-- doc_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- _el1: string (nullable = true)
|-- _el3: string (nullable = true)
|-- _el4: string (nullable = true)
|-- _el5: string (nullable = true)
```

I try in select:

```
explode('msp_contracts').select(
 col(u'msp_contracts.element._el1'),
 col(u'msp_contracts.element._el2')
)
```

but I can have error:

```
'Column' object is not callable
```

Comment: try: `df.selectExpr("inline_outer(msp_contracts)").drop("_VALUE", "_el2").show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `explode('msp_contracts')` spark will add **`col`** column as a result of explode (if alias in not provided).

```
df.select("doc_id",explode("msp_contracts")).show()
#+------+---+
#|doc_id|col|
#+------+---+
#|     1|[1]|
#+------+---+
```

Use **`col`** to select `_el1`, Try with `df_1.select("doc_id",explode("msp_contracts")).select("doc_id",col(u"col._el1")).show()`

**`Example:`**

```
jsn='{"doc_id":1,"msp_contracts":[{"_el1":1}]}'
df=spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([(jsn)]))

#schema
#root
# |-- doc_id: long (nullable = true)
# |-- msp_contracts: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- _el1: long (nullable = true)

df.withColumn("msp_contracts",explode(col("msp_contracts"))).\
select("doc_id","msp_contracts._el1").show()
#+------+----+
#|doc_id|_el1|
#+------+----+
#|     1|   1|
#+------+----+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

```
df.select("doc_id",explode("msp_contracts")).\
select("doc_id","col._el1").\
show()
#or
df.select("doc_id",explode("msp_contracts")).\
select("doc_id",col(u"col._el1")).\
show()
#+------+----+
#|doc_id|_el1|
#+------+----+
#|     1|   1|
#+------+----+
```

Comment: It's not work for me. I need select in another dataframe. When I make select with your code I has error:  cannot resolve '`msp_contracts.el1`

Comment: `select()` *does* accept `col()`, not sure what you mean.

Comment: I have df_1 and need make df_2 with some columns from df_1. And when I try make       
        `col('doc_id'),
        explode(col('msp_contracts')).select(
            'msp_contracts.element.el1',
            'msp_contracts.element.el2'
        ),`  I have error: `'msp_contracts.element.el2' TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Comment: @АнтонБукреев, Please check my `Updated` answer!

Comment: @CPak, I was overlooked `.select` accepts `col("<col_name>"),"<col_name>"`.

Comment: `df.select("doc_id",explode("msp_contracts")).\
select("doc_id","col._el1")` - this variant  work

Answer (score 0):

Work for me:

```
df.select("doc_id",explode("msp_contracts")).\ 
   select("doc_id","col._el1")
```

With alias and costum column:

```
df.select(
        'doc_id',
        explode('msp_contracts').alias("msp_contracts")
        )\
        .select(
            'doc_id',
            col('msp_contracts.el_1').alias('last_period_44fz_customer'),
            col('msp_contracts.el_2').alias('last_period_44fz_customer_inn')
        )\
        .withColumn("load_dtm", now_f())
```